# Detect multiple strings in one df from strings in another df and, if detected, return the strings detected

Tags: r, string, tags, mapply

I'm learning to use R, so please bear with me.

I have a dataset of google play store apps (master_tib). Each row is a play store app. There's a column titled description that contains text on what the app does.

```
master_tib

App     Description
App1    Reduce your depression and anxiety
App2    Help your depression 
App3    This app helps with Anxiety 
App4    Dog walker app 3000
```

I also have a df of tags (master_tags) that contains words of importance I've predefined. There is a single column titled tag and each row contains a single tag.

```
master_tag

Tag
Depression
Anxiety
Stress
Mood
```

My goal is to tag apps from the master_tib df with the tags in master_tags df based on the presence of the tag in the description. It will then print the tags in a new column. 
The final result would be a master_tib df that looks like this:

```
App     Description                            Tag
App1    Reduce your depression and anxiety     depression, anxiety
App2    Help your depression                   depression
App3    This app helps with anxiety            anxiety
App4    Dog walker app 3000                    FALSE
```

Below is what I've done so far using a combination of str_detect and mapply:

```
# define function to use in mapply

detect_tag <- function(description, tag){ 
  if(str_detect(description, tag, FALSE)) {
    return (tag)
  } else { 
    return (FALSE)
  }
}

index <-  mapply(FUN = detect_tag, description = master_tib$description, master_tags$tag)

master_tib[index,]
```

Unfortunately, only the first tag is being passed through.

```
App     Description                            Tag
App1    Reduce your depression and anxiety     depression
```

Instead of the desired:

```
App     Description                            Tag
App1    Reduce your depression and anxiety     depression, anxiety
```

I haven't gotten as far as printing the results into a new column. Would love to hear anyone's insight or thoughts and apologize in advance for my poor R skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the words from  `master_tag` using `str_c` and use `str_extract_all` to get all the words that match the pattern.

```
library(stringr)
master_tib$Tag <- sapply(str_extract_all(tolower(master_tib$Description), 
              str_c('\\b', tolower(master_tag$Tag), '\\b', collapse = "|")), 
              function(x) toString(unique(x)))
master_tib$Tag
#[1] "depression, anxiety" "depression"          "anxiety"             ""
```

**data**

```
master_tag <- structure(list(Tag = c("Depression", "Anxiety", "Stress", "Mood"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

master_tib <- structure(list(App = c("App1  ", "App2  ", "App3  ", "App4  "
), Description = c("Reduce your depression and anxiety", "Help your depression", 
"This app helps with Anxiety", "Dog walker app 3000")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I applied this to my dataset, the result kept every instance of a matched word. As a result, descriptions that mentions depression multiple times returned with depression depression depression depression. Is there a way to remove the duplicates within each row so that depression appears once per row with a match?

Comment: @jsole Yes, we can take only `unique` values. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using several packages from `tidyverse`(`dplyr`, `stringr`, `tidyr`) and the data shown in @Ronak Shah's answer.
First transform the tags into a pattern:

```r
pattern <- master_tags$Tag %>%
  tolower() %>%
  str_c(collapse="|")
```

Then find all matches and create the desired output:

```
master_tib %>%
  mutate(Tag = str_extract_all(tolower(Description), pattern)) %>%
  unnest(Tag, keep_empty = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(App, Description) %>% 
  summarise(Tag = str_c(Tag, collapse=", "))
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   App [4]
  App   Description                        Tag                
  <chr> <chr>                              <chr>              
1 App1  Reduce your depression and anxiety depression, anxiety
2 App2  Help your depression               depression         
3 App3  This app helps with Anxiety        anxiety            
4 App4  Dog walker app 3000                NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @RonakShah's answer, but with base R:

```r
apply(
  sapply(master_tag$Tag, grepl, master_tib$Description, ignore.case = TRUE),
  1, function(a) paste(master_tag$Tag[a], collapse = ","))
# [1] "Depression,Anxiety" "Depression"         "Anxiety"           
# [4] ""
```

(and without lower-casing or "comma-space" niceties, that is easily added if desired).